# jquery function executing multiple time for bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

```
$(document).on('click', '.event_class', function() {

    $('#originalImageShow').modal('show');

    $('#originalImageShow').on('shown.bs.modal',  function() {
        alert('Modal Open');
    });
    $('#originalImageShow').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        alert('Modal Close');
        $('#originalImageShow').off();
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });

});
```

Hi,
Each time I click the event_class It shows "Modal Open" alert twice. Even sometimes it shows multiple times. And also when I close the Bootstrap Modal sometimes it shows "Modal Close" alert multiple times.
Basically number of alert number is changing randomly.
Please help.

Comment: Put your code in jsfiddle.net (html/css/js) so we can check it "live". Please make sure you put there only the basic code that shows the problem. No one wants to go over hundreds of lines of code that do nothing.

Comment: @Dekel thank you. Let me show you my real problem.
Please visit https://www.ourbazaar.net/cropperTest.html
click on an image, rotate it. it's working fine but if you close the modal open another image and try to rotate again it will rotate twice in one click, close the modal and open another modal by clicking an image try to rotate it will rotate three times, same case for zoom in and zoom out. I think the problem is for bs-modal. you can get the code from https://gist.github.com/muradhassan/1693f614e72ac015d6fd.
I can't use jsfiddle because Cross-Origin Resource problem is occurring for image

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are adding **shown.bs.modal** inside on click function which will bind event every time modal is created!

Check out the below code

```js
$('.launchConfirm').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#confirm')
        .modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        
});

$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal',  function() {
        alert('Modal Open');
    });

$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        alert('Modal Close');
    });
```

```css
body,
.modal-open .page-container,
.modal-open .page-container .navbar-fixed-top,
.modal-open .modal-container {
 overflow-y: scroll;
}

@media (max-width: 979px) {
 .modal-open .page-container .navbar-fixed-top{
  overflow-y: visible;
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/css/bootstrap-modal.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
<script src="http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js"></script>



<div class="page-container">
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <button class="btn launchConfirm">Launch Confirm</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="confirm" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-body">
    Do you want to continue?
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" data-value="1">Continue</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" data-value="0">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Pratik Shah But I need to use shown.bs.modal inside the click event shown.bs.modal Let me show you my real problem. Please visit https://www.ourbazaar.net/cropperTest.html click on an image, rotate it. it's working fine but if you close the modal open another image and try to rotate again it will rotate twice in one click, close the modal and open another modal by clicking an image try to rotate it will rotate three times, same case for zoom in and zoom out. I think the problem is for bootstrap modal hide. you can get the code from gist.github.com/muradhassan/1693f614e72ac015d6fd